# Creating multiple docytpe documents using external API in frappe framew

Tags: python, orm, erpnext, frappe, frappe-charts

I'm new to frappe framework and have been trying to use this for past week now.
I wanted to create multiple doctypes from an API that returns a list of json objects from GET call.
How do I do that, also help me navigate me in terms of files as I'm new to this
Currently I've been editing in the <doctype>.py file

this is the code I wrote

```
import frappe
from frappe.model.document import Document
import requests

class todolist(Document):
    # pass
    def new_document(self):
        doctype_name = "todo-list"
        json_data = (requests.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos")).json()
        for json_object in json_data:
            new_doc = frappe.get_doc({
                "doctype": doctype_name,
                "id": json_object["id"],
                "title": json_object["title"],
                "completed": json_object["completed"],
            })
        
        new_doc.insert()
```

whenever I run this file I get an error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'frappe.model'`

I wanted to save the data into my doctype from an external GET request but I am getting issues with running frappe.
Installed [Frappe-Docker from github](https://github.com/frappe/frappe_docker), created new site and app, linked both, manually created a doctype and then tried editing that python file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using frappe version 14 or above.
Here is the command to check bench version

```
bench --version
```

Command(s) to update/upgrade frape:

```
bench update
pip install --upgrade frappe
```